# Grabbing values sent to a console application in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

What I'm trying to accomplish I have a textbox control and a button control on a form. When clicked whatever is entered into the textbox control, I want to send that data to a console application, which in turn create a text file. I have it mostly working but I can't get the data sent from the web application. How do I accomplish this? Here is what I have so far.

Here is my sub to send to the console application:

```
    Public Sub send_to_console()

    Dim file As String = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestConsoleApp\TestConsoleApp\bin\Debug\TestConsoleApp.exe"
    Dim info As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo(file, TextBox1.Text)

    Dim p As Process = Process.Start(info)

    End Sub
```

Console App Code:

```
 ublic Sub Main(ByVal args As String)

    Dim w As StreamWriter
    Dim filepath As String = "C:\xml_files\testFile.txt"

    Dim new_string As String
    new_string = "This has been completed on " & Date.Now

    If args = "" Then
        new_string = "No data entered on: " & Date.Now
    Else
        new_string = args & " " & Date.Now
    End If

    If System.IO.File.Exists(filepath) Then
        File.Delete(filepath)
    End If

    w = File.CreateText(filepath)

    w.WriteLine(new_string)
    w.Flush()
    w.Close()

End Sub
```

Currently i'm getting an error: no accessible Main

'#######################EDITS###########

```
  Dim file As String = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestConsoleApp\TestConsoleApp\bin\Debug\TestConsoleApp.exe"
    Dim info As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo(file, TextBox1.Text)
    info.UseShellExecute = False

    Dim p As Process = Process.Start(info)
```

Comment: You've dropped the P of Public but If this were the case then I doubt that you could have created an executable (.exe) file from your Console application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

main takes an array of string not a string.

so

```
Public Sub Main(ByVal args As String())
    .....

    If args.length < 1 Then
        new_string = "No data entered on: " & Date.Now
    Else
        new_string = args(0) & " " & Date.Now
    End If
    .....
End Sub
```

In order to prevent windows from splitting your arguments concatenate a quote character before and after

```
Dim info As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo(file, """" & TextBox1.Text & """")
```

Four double quote characters represent a string literal containing a single double quote.

Comment: @Will Pass the argument between quotes `"John Smith"`.

Comment: I think arguments passed to a console app will be broken up into arrays `args` by space as delimiter. Therefore, if your app expect text (i.e: `John Smith` as the only argument, you will have to join the `args()` to form the text.

Comment: Is there no other way that it passes arguments. The reason i'm asking is that i was going to try to pass xml string and there could be space thought the xml string?

Comment: @Will When I create a basic console application and I display the arguments, I do get `"John Smith"` as one single element in the `args` array... You might be doing something wrong.